# Python web.py sessions

Tags: python, session-variables, web.py

I am using web.py and trying to get the login working. I want to use a the session for when I login so that on next page reload I could display profile information.
The following code is for trying to set the session in the login ajax call

```
result = db.query("SELECT ...';")

session.client = result[0]
session.logged = True
return session.client
```

I am using diskStore with the following code

```
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={'count': 0})
```

Afterwards on page load I am trying to get the client from the session and send it to the template but its giving me 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'logged' for the following code:

```
if session.logged == True:
    client = session.get('client')
return self.render.loginPage("Profile", client)
```

What is wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to store the session obect in the configuration like describeed [here](http://webpy.org/cookbook/session_with_reloader):

```
if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), {'count': 0})
    web.config._session = session
else:
    session = web.config._session
```

Comment: its still giving me 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'logged'. I have bypassed this issue and am using cookies to serve the purpose

Comment: could you post more code? So it would be easier to run it and see the error